# Gatling Get web service

Tags: scala, gatling

I have tried to create a simple Gatling Script mentioned below,

package computerdatabase.advanced

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import scala.concurrent.duration._



class getSampleTest extends Simulation{

val httpProtocol = http
.baseURL("https://xyz.com")
.header("Content-Type","application/json")
.header("Accept"," application/json ")
.header("Accept-Charset","utf-8n")
.acceptLanguageHeader("en-us","en;q=0.5")
.acceptEncodingHeader("gzip", "deflate")
.connection("keep-alive")


val scn = scenario("XYZ")
.group("XYZ Group") {
exec(http("XYZ-PAge").get("/profile/services").check(status.is(200)))
}
setUp(scn.inject(
rampUsersPerSec(1) to(10) during(5), 
constantUsersPerSec(10) during(5)
).protocols(httpProtocol))

}
```

but i am getting an error saying that -->
value header is not a member of io.gatling.http.config.httpProtocolBuilder
may be a semicolon is missing before'value header'
.header("Content-Type","application/json")

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the compiler error message you get with such code (this is the error you got with the first tentative you posted on the Gatling mailing list).

Here, you get "too many arguments for method acceptLanguageHeader" (and acceptEncodingHeader) as those take only one parameter:

```
.acceptLanguageHeader("en-us, en;q=0.5")
.acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
```

Comment: ndle\gatling-charts-highcharts-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
20:50:58.858 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ - C:\gatling-charts-highcharts-2.0.0-20
140922.162052-88-bundle\gatling-charts-highcharts-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT\user-files\simu
lations\computerdatabase\advanced\CPC.scala:30: value headers is not a member of
 io.gatling.http.config.HttpProtocolBuilder
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value headers'?
20:50:58.863 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ - .headers(sentHeaders)
20:50:58.864 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -  ^
20:51:01.354 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ - one error found
Compilation failed

Comment: Hi Stephane, i have changed as per your instructions but the same error pops up .... above i have attached the full error ...

Comment: Come on!!! The compiler very explicitly tells you that you have a syntax error in a class named "CPC", and you're providing a class named "getSampleTest" that doesn't even contain a call to the "headers" method!